# UIScrollView with variable height

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, uitextview

I have a scrollView with a UIView as subview, which in turn has many subviews, one of which is a textView with variable height. This is the hierarchy of views:

```
-UIScrollView
   - UIView
       -UITextView with variable height
       -UImages
```

As can dynamically vary the height of the UIView and finally the scrollView based on the length of the content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the user edits your `UITextView` field, get its bounds height and recalculate the overall size of you scrollable view, then set `UIScrollView`'s `contentSize` property.

You can detect the end of editing on a `UITextView` object by means of its `UITextViewDelegate` `textViewDidEndEditing:` method.